# Give access to admin for all branches in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have created a Discussion Forum website where I provide branches to users dynamically. while registration user can select the branch and after login, the user will see only those posts which are related to his selected branch. this functionality works fine for users  but when I log in to the admin panel(I have created an admin dashboard where the admin will manage posts and replies. In my case admin is a superuser) an error occurs `DoesNotExist at /forum Register matching query does not exist.` I know this error comes because I haven't assigned any branch to the admin. But if I will assign any branch to the admin then he will be able to see only a particular branch's posts. But I want the admin can see all branch posts, not a specific branch post. Is there a way to do this if yes please help me to do this

model.py
Post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
user1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
post_id = models.AutoField
post_content = models.TextField(max_length=5000,verbose_name="")
timestamp= models.DateTimeField(default=now)
branch=models.CharField(default='',max_length=200)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",default="")
def __str__(self):
   return f'{self.user1} Post'
```

Reply model

```
class Replie(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
reply_id = models.AutoField
reply_content = models.TextField(max_length=5000,verbose_name="")
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
timestamp= models.DateTimeField(default=now)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",default="")
def __str__(self):
   return f'{self.user1} Post'
```

view.py
forum view

```
def forum(request):
user = request.user
profile = Profile.objects.all()
user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
data = Register.objects.get(user = user)
user_posts = Post.objects.filter(branch=data.branch).count()
if request.method=="POST":   
      user = request.user
      image = request.user.profile.image
      content = request.POST.get('content','')
      branch = request.POST.get('branch','')
      title = request.POST.get('title','')
      post = Post(user1=user, post_content=content, image=image,branch=branch,title=title)
      post.save()
      messages.success(request, f'Your Question has been posted successfully!!')
      return redirect('/forum') 
posts = Post.objects.filter(branch=data.branch).order_by('-timestamp')
print(data.branch)
context={
'posts':posts,
    'branch':data.branch,
    'user_posts':user_posts
}
return render(request, "forum.html",context)
```

forum.html

```
{% if user.is_superuser or user.is_staff %}
{% include "instructor/admin_nav.html" %}
{% else %}
 {% include "user/user_nav.html" %}
{% endif %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container my-4 ">
<div class="jumbotron"style="margin-bottom: 5%;    text-align: center;">
{% if user.is_superuser or user.is_staff %}
 <h3 class="display-4 font"> Disscussion Forum</h3>
<center class="lead post">Welcome to our discussion forum. You can post your question or any related queries by simply clicking on the add post button.</center>
<hr class="my-4 hr1">
<p class="post">You can also reply to others post by clicking on add or see reply button.</p>
{% else %}
 <h1 class="font mt-0"> {{branch}}   Disscussion Forum</h1>
<center >Welcome to  discussion forum. You can post your question or any related queries by simply clicking on the add post button.</center>
  <p>You can also reply to others post by clicking on add or see reply button.</p>
  <hr class="my-4 h">
<small>keep all posts on the topic. 
Any posts deemed to be in the wrong category will be removed.</small><br>
{% endif %}
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text bluebtn" data-target="#questions" data-toggle="modal" role="button">Add Post</button>
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
</div>
{% if user_posts == 0 %}
<div class="jumbotron">
 <h4 class="display-4">No Results fountd</h4>
<p class="lead">Be the first person to ask question</p>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="container-fluid mt-10">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card mb-4 forumcardcss">
              <div class="card-header forumcardheader">
                  <div class="media flex-wrap w-100 align-items-center imgcss"> <img src="/media/{{post.image}}" 
                          class="d-block ui-w-40 rounded-circle" alt="profileimage"style="width: 40px;height: 40px;">  <p class="ml-4 usernamecss">  {{post.user1}} </p>
                       <div class="media-body ml-3">
                      </div>
 <div class="text-muted small ml-3">
                        <div class="px-4 pt-3 f" >  {{post.timestamp}} </div>
                      </div>
                       {% if user.is_superuser or user.is_staff %}
                        <a href="{% url 'dashboard:delete_post' post.id %}"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm text" onclick="window.mytest()"style="background-color: #e60000;">Delete</button></a>
                        <script type="text/javascript">window.mytest = function() { var isValid = confirm('If you click ok then its delete this post and related reply on it. Are you sure to delete?');if (!isValid) { event.preventDefault();  alert("It wont delete. Yay!");}}</script>
                        {% endif %}
                      </div>
                   </div>         
               <div class="card-body forumcardbody">
                  <p class="text">{{ post.post_content|linebreaks|truncatewords_html:10 }}</p>{% if post.post_content|length|get_digit:"-1" > 50 %} 
               <a href="/discussion/{{post.id}}" data-abc="true"><button class="btn btn-light text" style="color:blue; font-size: 13px;">Show more </button>  </a>
             {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="questions" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
  

<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
</div>
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form action="/forum" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
<label style="font-size:1rem; font-weight:bold;">Post Your Question Here</label>

<textarea class="form-control" id="content" name="content" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <h3>Please Login to post</h3>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
 </div>

 {% endblock body %}
```

urls.py

```py
app_name = "dashboard"
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('user_home', views.user_home, name="user_home"),
    path('admin_home', views.admin_home, name="admin_home"),
    path("forum", views.forum, name="forum"),
    path("discussion/<int:myid>", views.discussion, name="discussion"),
    path("showallusers", views.show_all_users, name="showallusers"),
    path('delete_user/<int:pk>', views.delete_user, name="delete_user"),
    path('delete_post/<int:pk>', views.delete_post, name="delete_post"),
    path('delete_reply/<int:pk>', views.delete_reply, name="delete_reply"),
    path('upload_notes', views.upload_notes, name='upload_notes'),
    path('view_mynotes', views.view_mynotes, name='view_mynotes'),
    path('delete_mynotes/<int:pk>/', views.delete_mynotes, `name='delete_mynotes'), `
    path('pending_notes', views.pending_notes, name='pending_notes'),
    path('assign_status/<int:pk>', views.assign_status, name='assign_status'),
    path('accepted_notes', views.accepted_notes, name='accepted_notes'),
    path('rejected_notes', views.rejected_notes, name='rejected_notes'),
    path('all_notes', views.all_notes, name='all_notes'),
    path('delete_notes/<int:pk>', views.delete_notes, name='delete_notes'),
    path('delete-records/', views.delete_notes, name='delete_notes'),
    path('view_allnotes', views.view_allnotes, name='view_allnotes'),
    path('notessharing', views.notessharing, name='notessharing'),
    path('edit_post/<int:pk>/', views.edit_post, name='edit_post'),
    path('edit_reply/<int:pk>/', views.edit_reply, name='edit_reply'),
]
```

User Register model

```
class Register(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
branch= models.CharField(max_length=100)
def __str__(self):
   return self.user.username
```

Comment: Can you share urls.py for this?

Comment: this code link is 6 days old and in this source code, I haven't written code to take branch while registration. I present time I just add a `<select >` tag in the register.html

Comment: For all branches try `posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')`.

Comment: but I want to show post to user according to their branch  If I try `posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')`  then It will show all posts to all users

Comment: for this, I create a new forum view  for admin in which I user `posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')`  but in this case I have to create pages for all post's brach

Comment: Try `Post.objects.filter(user1__is_superuser=True).order_by('-timestamp')`.

Comment: I am still getting this error `DoesNotExist at /forum
Register matching query does not exist.
`

Comment: Have you attached your user with `Profile` model correctly?

Comment: Yes my profile model is `class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,default="1", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile",verbose_name="")
   
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",default="default/user.png")
    `

Comment: Try `data = Register.objects.get(user=request.user.id)` or `data = Register.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)` see which doesn't give the error.

Comment: same error occurs `DoesNotExist at /forum
Register matching query does not exist.`

Comment: Are you really trying my view which i shown in answer, exact copy that, and are you must logged in.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is you have to do separate queries for the users, for superuser, it should display all the branches, the query should be :

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(user1__is_superuser=True).order_by('-timestamp')
```

and for normal user to display selected branches it should be:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(branch=data.branch).order_by('-timestamp')
```

Try this view:

```
def forum(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.all()
    data = get_object_or_404(Register,user=request.user)
    user_posts = Post.objects.filter(branch=data.branch).count()
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user
        image = request.user.profile.image
        content = request.POST.get('content', '')
        branch = request.POST.get('branch', '')
        title = request.POST.get('title', '')
        post = Post(user1=user, post_content=content,
                    image=image, branch=branch, title=title)
        post.save()
        messages.success(
            request, f'Your Question has been posted successfully!!')
        return redirect('/forum')

    if request.user.is_superuser:
        posts = Post.objects.filter(user1__is_superuser=True).order_by('-timestamp')
    else:
        posts = Post.objects.filter(branch=data.branch).order_by('-timestamp')


    print(data.branch)
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'branch': data.branch,
        'user_posts': user_posts
    }
    return render(request, "forum.html", context)
```

Comment: yes I  just copy and paste  and refresh page to see results

Comment: @Ajay I think `user_posts = Post.objects.filter(branch=data.branch).count()` this line causing some problem, can you please comment it and then check.

Comment: or maybe this `image=request.user.profile.image` causing problem.

Comment: should I have to create two separate view for forum

Comment: @Ajay Yes, you can also do that, but I didn't understand that error.

Comment: this error comes because I haven't given any branch to admin

Comment: @Ajay I have used `get_object_or_404` for Register model, check out edited answer, see if it helps, or also how are you registering the admin users which are superusers, can you share that view?